# Algorithm to prepare laining

Tags: memory, torah-reading

It takes me forever to prepare laining (i.e. to memorize the trop).

Does anyone know of an algorithm, whether brought down anywhere or not, of how to prepare quickly and efficiently?

I.e. just read the whole aliya a million times?
Or just read one posuk until the got it, then prepare 2 pesukim in a row, then 3, etc.?